# Can I implement the reverse geocoding function within my ActivityMaps.java file?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Im currently developing an app in Android Studio 1.1.0 and I have implemented the Google Maps API from where I can retrieve a users current location but I would like to convert this into an address. Can I use the following code in my MapsActivity.java file?

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {

   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
   // This is making the Geocode request
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
      if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        }

    // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results);

        var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
    }
});
```

}

Any help will be appreciated. Still relatively new to Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using the **android.location.Geocoder**.

```
 // get current locality based on lat lng
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

For a good practice make sure you do this inside an AsyncTask.